# Dawnport Testing Vocations

Tags: tibia

If I'm in Dawnport and I am testing as a vocation (e.g. Knight). If I reach level 9 do I gain the stats upon leveling that the vocation I'm testing would gain (e.g. additional capacity) or do I gain the stats a non-vocation character would gain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll gain 5 life, 5 mana and 10 Oz (capacity) for each level even after level 8.

Attention: If you go to the main land above level 8 as a Knight you'll have lost 10 life points and 15 Oz for each level. Only level up above 9+ in dawnport if you want to keep you character there.

Comment: This is what I figured would happen but didn't quite want to waste the time to test it myself as I have no intention to keep a character at Dawnport. Thanks for the confirmation!